# Which keyboard layout do I choose on installation

Tags: installation, keyboard, keyboard-layout

When installing I am presented a rather lengthy list of keyboard layouts to choose from:

[image]

Choosing the default layout on top of the list seems fine but I am wondering what differences there are between the other layouts in this list. How do I find out what layout fits my keyboard best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should either test your selection in the little text box, or use the "Detect" option. It works extremely well.

[image]

Note that you can always change your keyboard layout after the installation (*Preferences → Keyboard → Layout*). If you do, you get this rather helpful dialogue:

[image]

<sup>(of course, resizable) :)</sup>

Comment: Indeed, the detect layout function is great! The preview however can not be displayed when installing.

Comment: How can I access this "detect layout" option if ubuntu is *already* installed? I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and try to find it under "System Settings -> Keyboard Layout" but with no luck.

Comment: "detect layout" tells me "Lithuanian". Also, the "type a key" box appears behind the popup, so first I thought it hung, then I decided to move the popup and I saw the other popup.  Oh well.... I just chose "English US", I think that's the most practical, even if I type in foreign languages a lot.