# How to type @ from keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I need to know how to make @ in Ubuntu with keyboard keys. In windows the keyboard keys are <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> but in Ubuntu its different. If you know please help.

Comment: What keyboard layout (language) are you using? Maybe answers to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/46172/3940) help.

Comment: What do you mean by "the keyboard keys"?

Comment: Are there particular programs you use this in, like Libre Office, or are you talking everything?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using US (international) layout you need to press
<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>.

Comment: And on a UK/Irish keyboard, the `"` and the `@` keys are swapped, so for us it's `Shift+'`. (This is annoying when my computer randomly resets itself to US layout, because I have an `@` symbol in my password and then I can't see it. (The Windows computer I use in work occasionally decides it's going to the States without warning me. The Ubuntu computer I use at home is better behaved and never does this.))

Answer (score 1):

Try the AltGr key:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> should result in @

Comment: That's in the German keyboard layout, isn't it? Not here in Ireland.